# sendTransform() takes exactly 6 arguments (2 given)

Tags: ros

I was trying to run [this](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher) tutorial in python code, but i got above error when i try to run it. My python converted program of given tutorial is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from std_msgs.msg import Header
import tf
import geometry_msgs.msg
import math

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('joint_states', JointState, queue_size=1)
    rospy.init_node('state_publisher')

broadcaster = tf.TransformBroadcaster()   
rate = rospy.Rate(30) # 10hz 
M_PI = 3.145
degree = M_PI/180;

# robot state
tilt = 0 
tinc = degree 
swivel=0 
angle=0 
height=0 
hinc=0.005

# message declarations
t = geometry_msgs.msg.TransformStamped()
hello_str = JointState()
t.header.frame_id = "odom"
t.child_frame_id = "axis"

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    # update joint_state
    hello_str.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    hello_str.name = ['swivel','tilt','periscope']
    hello_str.position = swivel
    hello_str.velocity = tilt
    hello_str.effort = height

    t.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    t.transform.translation.x = math.cos(angle)*2
    t.transform.translation.y = math.sin(angle)*2
    t.transform.translation.z = .7
    #t.transform.rotation = tf.createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(angle+M_PI/2)
    t.transform.rotation = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, angle)
    # send the joint state and transform
    pub.publish(hello_str)
    broadcaster.sendTransform(t)

    # Create new robot state
    tilt += tinc
    if (tilt<-.5 or tilt>0):
       tinc *= -1
    height += hinc
    if (height>.2 or height<0):
      hinc *= -1
    swivel += degree
    angle += degree/4

    rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

How can i remove this, i am using ros indigo. Even if i change that line with :

`broadcaster.sendTransform((0.5,1.0,0),tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, angle+M_PI/2),rospy.Time.now(),"odom","axis")` 
Its not working. Than it shows error:

```
 field position must be a list or tuple type
[state_pub-2] process has died [pid 11654, exit co
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in Python, the function `sendTransform` has interface a but different from the same function in `C++`.

If you run the following code:

```
import tf
br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
br.sendTransform?
```

you will see that `sendTransform` should be called like this:

`br.sendTransform(translation, rotation, time, child, parent)`

You may have a look at [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20(Python)) for an example code.

Comment: ok, thanks, although i tried this method previously also but got some error when i try to echo the /joint_state topic, like now. i can calearly visualize the child frame moving in rviz now as i tried.

Comment: I think that's what I addressed in my answer: you're probably passing a numpy array instead of a list (if you're doing what you showed in the last part of your question)

Comment: Ok, after i changed hello_str.position = swivel with hello_str.position = [swivel,swivel,swivel], i can now see the joints moving.

Answer (score 0):

"transformations", if I remember right was initially part of an external script, where quaternion_from_euler returns a numpy array of four values.

https://w3.cs.jmu.edu/spragunr/CS354_S14/labs/tf_lab/html/tf.transformations-module.html#quaternion_from_euler

https://gist.github.com/baalexander/5225140

sendTransform on the other hand, expects a **list** of values for the rotation argument. The way you're passing the rotation part right now, as the output of quaternion_from_euler would cause a numpy array to be passed instead of a list. You'd probably have to load the numpy array contents manually into a list and pass it to sendTransform.